# Closing StreamReader

Tags: java, http, streamreader

After getting a response from a server (by sending http request), I try to fetch a content as follows:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    if (entity == null) {
        ...
    }

    String content;
    try {
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        content = IOUtils.toString(reader);
        reader.close();
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ...
    }
```

Is it necessary to close the reader (`reader.close()`)? Or `EntityUtils.consume(entity)` is enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good practice. When using resources that allow for "cleanup" just go for it. 
And the simple way is to use try-with-resources:

```
try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), "UTF-8"); 
     Reader reader = new BufferedReader()) {
    content = IOUtils.toString(reader);
    EntityUtils.consume(entity);
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
}
```

Meaning: the Java language already gives you the means to have that happen automatically.

Comment: so if I use Java 6, I should close reader in finally section?

Comment: Yes. And try to move forward. Java 6 is like: bad idea :-)

Comment: should I consume entity also in finally section?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `try-with-resources`-statement:

```
try(Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), "UTF-8"))) {
    content = IOUtils.toString(reader);
    EntityUtils.consume(entity);
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
}
```

Which already closes the reader for you.

For Java 6 you should use the following:

```
Reader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), "UTF-8"));
    content = IOUtils.toString(reader);
    EntityUtils.consume(entity);
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
} finally {
    if(reader != null){
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch(IOException e){
            // can not be closed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so if I use Java 6, I should close reader in finally section?

Comment: should I consume entity also in finally section?

Comment: @ru51an depends on what that consume does. Is it in any case related to reading the content? Does it access any resources, like files, databases and so on?

Comment: entity is used only in that part of code that I published above

Comment: You might want to call that `EntityUtils.consume()` outside of the try catch. As it doesn't really belong there. You should put the least amount of code into a try-catch block, to minimize the possible errors and failures

Comment: Since the OP is already using `IOUtils` the `finally` block can just be `IOUtils.closeQuietly(reader);` which takes care of the null check and catching a secondary exception.